# SPL Token Renounce Ownership

Tags: spl-token

Question how would you renounce ownership for spl token you created ?

So like no one can mint or freeze ever again basically making it immutable

Answer (score 1):

You can disable minting and freezing by setting both authorities to `COption::None`. If you're using the CLI, that would be:

```
$ spl-token authorize <MINT_ADDRESS> mint --disable
$ spl-token authorize <MINT_ADDRESS> freeze --disable
```

Answer (score 0):

A straightforward way would be to set the mint and the freeze authorities to something like

`11111111111111111111111111111111`

or any other account that can never sign anything.

Strictly speaking, this doesn't relate to "ownership" but to the two kinds of "authority" (mint / freeze) over the mint. "ownership" in Solanaland typically refers either to the program that owns an account or wallet that owns a particular token account.